# ScrollView shows lot of chars when there's large amounts of text

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, mobile, layout

I tried to add scrollView into my fragment, but it does not work, for the large text it shows that I have a lot of chars.

[image: screenshot]

I am getting Api from newsApi, all the information I got is from there.

I tried even to do everything in LinerLayout, I thought the problem is in constraintLayout maybe. But I'm not able to find it.

my xml:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECF0F5"
    tools:context=".ui.Fragments.DescriptionFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/return_from_des"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="Breaking News"
                android:textColor="#003C68"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="Apple's 2021 App Store Awards highlight 'connection'"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="In this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, FantasianIn this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, Fantasian"
                android:textColor="#A6A7A7"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desc_title"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="68dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/desc_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/image_ex"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desc_description" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_context"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="context"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desc_image" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/saved_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/float_p"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: Are you sure that text (including the *[+9999 chars]* bit) isn't what you're receiving from the API? Your XML looks fine to me for setting up a `ScrollView`, and standard `TextView`s don't truncate text like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the UI in 2 different layout

1. fragment.xml

   ```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     android:background="#ECF0F5"
        tools:context=".ui.Fragments.DescriptionFragment">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```

2.content_main.xml with remaining child UI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/return_from_des"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
                android:text="Breaking News"
                android:textColor="#003C68"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="Apple's 2021 App Store Awards highlight 'connection'"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="In this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, FantasianIn this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, Fantasian"
                android:textColor="#A6A7A7"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desc_title"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="68dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/desc_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desc_description" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_context"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="In this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, FantasianIn this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, Fantasian
In this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, FantasianIn this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, Fantasian
In this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, FantasianIn this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, FantasianIn this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, FantasianIn this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, Fantasian
In this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, FantasianIn this article: LumaFusion, Craft, news, gear, Carrot Weather, Space Marshals 3, gaming, Dazn, League of Legends: Wild Rift, Myst, Apple, Among Us, Canva, Toca Life World, Penaut, MARVEL Future Revolution, App Store Awards. Bumble, Fantasian"

                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desc_image" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now change fonts and images as per your Original UI and try once.